# Google load balancer with apache rewrite engine (mod_rewrite) won't work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I recently set up a load balancer with Google Compute Engine to manage SSL certificates for me for my apache instance. (simple website)

But I am very confused. I am using a rewrite engine to change the clients URL to the proper one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?example?\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%examples.co%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

*Rewrites: http to https, www to non-www, non-plural to plural, and all to TDL .co.*

This code works without a load balancer. But with a load balancer, it's completely useless.

I've put this code in my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` and also tried in my `000-default.conf` file as well. Yes I did an apache reset after each edit. Other configurations such as Document Root all work fine in these conf files.

I also did `sudo a2enmod rewrite` in case you're wondering. Also, I get no errors! Other mods such as VirtualDocumentRoot which I am also using in the same conf files work perfectly.

Both http and https websites work, but their urls are just not changing according to rewrite engine.

I've also tried to use the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/fZTGQmehNws) from Google forms, but with no success.

I am completely stumped on what to do at this point. Any ideas or suggestions. Am I missing headers or something? Why won't any of the RewriteEngine work?!

Comment: Please provide configuration of your load balancer.

Comment: Try to check access to you site with `mod_rewrite` disabled via `HTTP(S) Load balancer`. Also, have a look at the https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733 and https://serverfault.com/questions/733166.